# Boot problem empty fstab RedHat 3.7

Tags: redhat, boot

My server doesn't boot and I found that /etc/fstab file is empty.
When trying to update this file I see that the file is readonly.
I can't change the write permission, becuase the device is mounted readonly.
I can't remount with rw permission I get an error saying that the / doesn't appear in the /etc/fstab file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you remount the drive, refer to it by device name rather than simply `/`.  If it's mounted read only, you should be able to see the device name if you run `mount` with no parameters.  Then, run `mount -o remount,rw /dev/xxxx /` and it should be accessible again.

Comment: This should work. However, I would wonder how/why /etc/fstab has been truncated. It is possible that the root filesystem is seriously borked, so it might not be a good idea to mount it rw until after a fsck.

Comment: I managed to mount to the device and to update the fstab file.

Comment: I managed to mount to the device and to update the fstab file.
Now I still have the problem:
"fsck.ext2 /dev/root ...
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>"
I tried severals superblock values, but still it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check that /dev/root actually points to the right partition?  If the partition can be mounted at all, you shouldn't need any -b superblock option to fsck it.  If it's telling you it can't find an ext2fs superblock on it, then it's probably telling you the truth... is the partition really ext2 and not reiser or xfs?

Comment: How can I check that?
I'm new with Linux.

Comment: If it's mounted, running `mount` by itself should have a line like `/dev/sda1 on / type ext3`.  But if it's mounted you should absolutely not be running fsck against it!

Comment: After running mount I got:

Comment: /dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw)  
none on /proc type proc (rw)  
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)  
usbdevfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbdevfs (rw)  
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)  
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)

Comment: OK, so your root partition is `/dev/sda2` and is an `ext3` filesystem.  Ideally what you need to do is reboot and let fsck run at startup since you can't fsck a partition that is mounted rw.  If Linux doesn't think it needs a fsck then you can do `tune2fs -l /dev/sda2`, read the `Maximum mount count:` line and then `tune2fs -C max+1 /dev/sda2` so it thinks it's been mounted enough times to fsck.

Comment: It didn't help me solve the problem, so now I already after re-installing the server. Thanks for the help